# Maximisation of the distance of particles in a periodic box

Tags: geometry, optimization

Consider $N$ particles in a box of ratio $R=L_x/L_y$, where $L_x$ and $L_y$ are the two sides of the box. The box has periodic boundary conditions. Consider now a state which maximises the distance between these particles.

is there a known way to geometrically describe such a state?

More specifically, is there a known result which describes the geometry of the array of particles resulting from the periodic repetition of the box in terms of the ratio $R$ and the number of particles $N$?
(for instance in terms of the basic vectors ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf b}$ of the resulting lattice)

Comment: This question has already been asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339649/maximizing-distance-between-points). In my little experience, it's rather uncommon for these sort of problems to have exact analytical solutions.

Comment: That's correct. Or  if your lattice can be described by $F({\bf x})$ then you would have that $F({\bf x}+L_x)=F({\bf x})$ and $F({\bf x}+L_y)=F({\bf x})$.

Comment: It's a classic physics question of disc/sphere packing, and it has almost certainly been simulated before (with appropriate phase diagrams and so on). Search for jamming/hard disc potential/hard core packing/...

Comment: Okay, as I thought then. If you're doing this for fun, a helpful search term could be "geometrical packings", I think it's a closely-related problem. If on the other hand you need a quick answer for a project or something, I suggest going down the simulation route. In my research I came across the seemingly much simpler question "what's the most compact packing of $N$ discs?", and as far as I know this has only had successful [computational approaches](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/90_01_penny_packing.pdf), in general.

Comment: Yes, actually I can already achieve numerical results (in a related problem), but I was hoping to be able to compare with some analytical result. I guess it's asking too much...

Comment: Another [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314686/find-a-point-that-maximizes-total-distance-from-a-set-of-points-within-a-bounded) on StackOverflow. You could apply this iteratively as a "greedy algorithm", which in general does not guarantee optimal solutions for $N$, but in practice tends to give decent results (this is exactly what they did in that disc packing paper).

Comment: However is it not different the problem of the most compact packing of N discs in a square? For instance consider 4 discs in a closed box with $L_x/L_y=\sqrt{3}$: the maximum distance would be achieved with a rectangle. However if you have periodic boundary conditions you can actually have a triangular lattice because the discs can pass through the boundaries and be 'split in half'. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, you're right as far as I can tell. I was only pointing out a problem with a similar 'spirit' just to indicate that these problems don't always have (known) analytical solutions. And also to point out the use of greedy algorithms as good approximations.

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195000/2451